# Ошибка компиляции "no matching function for call" и необъяснимое "решение"

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Делаю универсальный шаблон контейнера, чтобы хранил объекты не только в памяти и чтобы работал с 'Range-based for loop' (то есть в стиле **for(auto i : items)**). Код еще не закончен, хочу разобраться с ошибкой, что-то никак не пойму

Имею базовый класс (шаблон):

```
template <class Key, class T>
class IContainer
{
public:
    class IOuterIterator
    {
    public:

        IOuterIterator() {}

        virtual T operator*() {return T();}

        virtual bool operator != (const IOuterIterator& other) {return false;}

    protected:


    private:

    };

    virtual IOuterIterator begin() = 0;
    virtual IOuterIterator end() = 0;

private:

};
```

некий производный класс Container

```
template <class Key, class T, class IteratorKey>
class Container : public IContainer<Key, T>
{
public:

    Container() : IContainer<Key, T>() {}

    class OuterIterator : public IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator
    {
    public:
        OuterIterator(Container<Key, T, IteratorKey> *container) :
            IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator(),
            _container(container)
        {
        }

        T operator*() override
        {
            return _container->value(_iteratorKey);
        }

        bool operator != (const typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator& other) override {
            OuterIterator oit(_container);
            oit = (OuterIterator)other; //ТУТ ОШИБКА!
            return (_iteratorKey != oit._iteratorKey);
        }

    private:
        //inner class objects don't have an implicit reference to an outer object.
        Container<Key, T, IteratorKey> *_container;
        IteratorKey _iteratorKey;
    };

    typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator begin() {
        return OuterIterator(this);//TODO: set to begin
    }
    typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator end() {
        return OuterIterator(this);//TODO: set to the end
    }

protected:
    virtual T value(Key key, const T &defaultValue) const = 0;
    virtual T value(IteratorKey ikey) = 0;

};
```

И импликация для контейнера с памятью:

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, Key>
{
    T value(Key key, const T &defaultValue) const override
    {
        return 0;//TODO:
    }

    T value(Key key) override
    {
        return 0;//TODO:
    }

};

//TODO: FileContainer, DBContainer, RemoteContainer
```

Вызов где-то в майне:

```
MemoryContainer<int, int> container;
```

Ошибка:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Container<int, int, int>::OuterIterator::OuterIterator(const IContainer<int, int>::IOuterIterator&)'
             oit = (OuterIterator)other;
                 ^
candidate: Container<Key, T, IteratorKey>::OuterIterator::OuterIterator(Container<Key, T, IteratorKey>*) [with Key = int; T = int; IteratorKey = int]
         OuterIterator(Container<Key, T, IteratorKey> *container) :
         ^
```

Самое смешное, что когда удаляю (комментю) функции begin() и end() из IContainer, ошибка необъяснимо пропадает (вернее она появилась, когда я добавил эти функции).

**Код файла main.cpp целиком (для копи-паста):**

```
#include <QMap>

template <class Key, class T>
class IContainer
{
public:
    class IOuterIterator
    {
    public:

        IOuterIterator() {}

        virtual T operator*() {return T();}

        virtual bool operator != (const IOuterIterator& other) {return false;}

    protected:


    private:

    };

    virtual IOuterIterator begin() = 0;
    virtual IOuterIterator end() = 0;

private:

};

template <class Key, class T, class IteratorKey>
class Container : public IContainer<Key, T>
{
public:

    Container() : IContainer<Key, T>() {}

    class OuterIterator : public IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator
    {
    public:
        OuterIterator(Container<Key, T, IteratorKey> *container) :
            IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator(),
            _container(container)
        {
        }

        T operator*() override
        {
            return _container->value(_iteratorKey);
        }

        bool operator != (const typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator& other) override {
            OuterIterator oit(_container);
            oit = (OuterIterator)other;
            return (_iteratorKey != oit._iteratorKey);
        }

    private:
        //inner class objects don't have an implicit reference to an outer object.
        Container<Key, T, IteratorKey> *_container;
        IteratorKey _iteratorKey;
    };

    typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator begin() {
        return OuterIterator(this);//TODO: set to begin
    }
    typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator end() {
        return OuterIterator(this);//TODO: set to the end
    }

protected:
    virtual T value(Key key, const T &defaultValue) const = 0;
    virtual T value(IteratorKey ikey) = 0;

private:

};

template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, Key>
{
    T value(Key key, const T &defaultValue) const override
    {
        return 0;//TODO:
    }

    T value(Key key) override
    {
        return 0;//TODO:
    }

};

//TODO: FileContainer, DBContainer, RemoteContainer

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
MemoryContainer<int, int> container;
IContainer<int, int> *_container1 = new MemoryContainer<int, int>();
}
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше сделали отрывок кода, который можно взять и скомпиллировать без изменений. А то, честно говоря, лень бывает склеивать из разных открывков.

Comment: @alexolut OK добавил

Comment: Вы не поняли, я имел в виду полностью готовый и самодостаточный исходник с `main`, при компиляции которого возникает описанная проблема.

Comment: @alexolut OK изменил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле, удивительно и странно не то, что эта ошибка появилась когда вы добавили begin и end в базовый класс - а то, что без них все работает.

Видимо, виноваты чудеса оптимизации, выкинувшие нерабочий код.

Посмотрим внимательнее на этот метод - настоящая ошибка в нем:

```
typename IContainer<Key, T>::IOuterIterator begin() {
    return OuterIterator(this);//TODO: set to begin
}
```

Здесь класс OuterIterator приводится к своему предку. **Но в C++ полиморфизм доступен только для ссылок и указателей**, а не для значений! Без оператора приведения типа этот код работать не должен.

---

Обычно решают эту проблему следующим образом - вводят промежуточное звено, для которого доступен полиморфизм.

То есть вводится, к примеру, класс `IContainer::iterator`, являющаяся общим для всех классов "фротэндом" - и абстрактный класс `IContainer::IIterator`, скрывающий детали реализации.

Первый класс держит указатель на второй:

```
class iterator {
  std::unique_ptr<IIterator> impl;
public:
  iterator(IIterator *impl) :impl(impl) { }
  //...
  T& operator *() { return impl->current(); }
  T operator *() const { return impl->current(); }
}
```

Однако, такой способ может привести к просадке производительности если тип контейнера хорошо известен - виртуальные вызовы обходятся не бесплатно.

Поэтому в финальном классе-наследнике есть смысл продублировать итератор, чтобы он использовал уже конкретную реализацию. Это можно сделать при помощи шаблонов (т.н. статический полиморфизм):

```
template<typename T> class wellknown_iterator {
  T impl;
public:
  wellknown_iterator(T &&impl) :impl(std::move(impl)) { }
  wellknown_iterator() { }
  //...
  T& operator *() { return impl.current(); }
  T operator *() const { return impl.current(); }
}
```

В таком случае, классы `IContainer` и `Container` смогут выглядеть примерно так:

```
class IContainer {
  //...
protected:
  virtual IIterator* create_iterator() = 0;

public:
  iterator begin() { return create_iterator(); }
  iterator end() { return nullptr; }
}

class Container : IContainer {
public:
  class Iterator : IIterator {
    // ...
  };

  //...      
protected:
  virtual IIterator* create_iterator() { return new Iterator(this); };

public:
  wellknown_iterator<Iterator> begin() { return Iterator(this); }
  wellknown_iterator<Iterator> end() { return wellknown_iterator<Iterator>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Суть итераторов как раз в том, что они являются "оберткой" вокруг указателя и используются всегда по значению. При возвращении из функции объекта производного класса, он преобразуется в объект базового класса (IOuterIterator) и забывает о том, кем он был. Поэтому даже после фикса ошибок архитектура не будет валидной - все итераторы будут работать как базовый, то есть никак.

Чтобы избежать такого, стоило сразу пометить методы IOuterIterator абстрактными (= 0) и предостеречь себя от неверных действий.

А ошибка из-за того, что нет конструктора OuterIterator из IOuterIterator.

---

Моё предложение фикса - IOuterIterator переименовать в IOuterIteratorImpl, создать дополнительные класс

```
template <class T>
class IOuterIterator {
    std::unique_ptr<IOuterIteratorImpl*> _impl;
    /* соответствующий код */
public:
    T& operator*() { return **_impl; };
    /* и так далее */
};
```

Тогда его можно будет использовать по значению, оставив прежний функционал.

Comment: Все эти усложнения для того, чтобы сделать возможным конструкцию вида:
    
 
   ` IContainer<int, int> *_container1 = new MemoryContainer<int, int>();` 
    


То есть, чтобы не указывать IteratorKey для каждого указателя и чтобы IteratorKey зависел от природы самого контейнера, а не был задан жестко